# How to plot residue of a complex polynomial which coefficients are function?

Tags: plotting, complex, polynomials

It is easy to find residue when we know roots of polynomials, such as :

`g[z_, t_] := 1 + t*z`

`Residue[1/(1 + t*z), {z, -1/t}]`

`1/t`

`Plot[1/t, {t, -5.1, 5.1}]`

[image]

but when polynomial is more complex, how do I can plot the residue when I don't know roots in explicit form ?(second example in the picture)

Comment: Your problem is with usage of `Root` rather than `Residue`. Try `Root[Function[z,g[z,t]],1]` so Mathematica knows which one is your variable, `t` or `z`; moreover `Root` cannot take a single function as an argument, it must be given indication which root to choose (even if there is only one to choose from)

Answer (score 3):

You need to indicate the variable and the root number.

By way of an example:

```
Residue[1/(z^3 + p z + q), {z, Root[#^3 + p # + q &, 1]}]
```

gives

```
1/(p + 3 Root[q + p #1 + #1^3 &, 1]^2)
```

and then

```
Plot3D[1/(p + 3 Root[q + p #1 + #1^3 &, 1]^2), {p, -3, 3}, {q, -3, 3}, 
    PlotPoints -> 75, MaxRecursion -> 5, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}]
```

gives

[image]

While if you choose another root, you get very different picture:

```
Plot3D[1/(p + 3 Root[q + p #1 + #1^3 &, 3]^2), {p, -3, 3}, {q, -3, 3}, 
    PlotPoints -> 75, MaxRecursion -> 5, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}]
```

results in

[image]

To see all branches together then, it might be better to try contour plot. First, find the implicit equation with

```
Eliminate[{h == 1/(p + 3 r^2), q + p r + r^3 == 0}, r]
```

which gives

```
27 h^3 q^2 == 1 + 3 h p - 4 h^3 p^3
```

and then do

```
ContourPlot3D[ 27 h^3 q^2 == 1 + 3 h p - 4 h^3 p^3, {p, -3, 3}, {q, -3, 3}, {h, -3, 3}, 
    MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, MaxRecursion -> 5]
```

to obtain

[image]

Comment: thank you very much, it was so helpful

Comment: how can I find residue in the second line more explicitly rather than Root[q + p #1 + #1^3 &, 1] in denominator?

Comment: Well in this particular case you have the Cardano formulae; solving `Solve[q + p x + x^3 == 0, x]` gives three roots in explicit radicals. But even in that case there are some subtleties when square radicals are complex but final roots might be real. So it seems better to use implicit equation with `Eliminate`

Comment: @Arian Just use `ToRadicals`.